# Can I write Erlang modules in Phoenix?

Tags: erlang, elixir, cowboy

Suppose I have a Phoenix webserver running with a bunch of routes and their corresponding handlers written in Elixir.

Can I add a new route path and write the corresponding handler in Erlang as a `.erl` file?

If not, what's the way to add a new handler written in Erlang into a Phoenix app?

Comment: Have you tried just adding the corresponding handler in [tag:erlang] and attach it to the route?